# add watermark through rendering pugin

Tags: css, grails, rendering

I am creating pdf by using rendering plugin in grails. I need to add watermark (its an image) in my pdf. I do not know how to add watermark in it. I searched on google but there is nothing about watermark by using rendering plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is actually not related to Grails or Rendering plugin. Question is related to `css`.

Add `background-image` in style for the pdf. The below will add watermark to all pages in pdf.

```
@page {
   background-image: url("your image here");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center;
}
```